# Maximize process from java from taskbar

Tags: java, jna

If I have a process minimized in my taskbar, is there any way to maximize it from java?

I know the name of the process, but would it be possible?

Comment: Is this *your* running program that you want to bring up or is it an arbitrary other program? Are you exclusively targeting Windows or another OS?

Comment: @cubrr  I'm only targeting Windows. I want to bring up a process that is already running.

Comment: To be more precise, open up a game from the taskbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably using the Windows API. I've used [Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) before for tasks like this. I've found the library very handy.

With JNA, what you do is you declare an interface with the exported functions of a shared library (DLL), then load the library which gets you proxy to that library.

The WinAPI functions we're interested in are the following User32 functions:

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindow(LPCTSTR lpClassName, LPCTSTR lpWindowName); 

BOOL WINAPI ShowWindow(HWND hWnd, int  nCmdShow);
```

Our proxy interface could look like this. This interface provides very low level access, so in practice you'd probably want to encapsulate the functionality.

```
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx
    int FindWindowA(String className, String windowName);
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
    boolean ShowWindow(int window, int command);
}
```

Notice that the function name must match the API function's name *exactly*. If you want to use Java-style method names (camelCase instead of PascalCase), you need a custom function mapper that does the change ([usage example](https://github.com/cxcorp/lacuna/blob/a94ea17d844f2081ae46bbb0f89d2f89b102f1ba/lacuna/lacuna-core/src/main/java/cx/corp/lacuna/core/LacunaBootstrap.java#L154), class [definition](https://github.com/cxcorp/lacuna/blob/a94ea17d844f2081ae46bbb0f89d2f89b102f1ba/lacuna/lacuna-core/src/main/java/cx/corp/lacuna/core/windows/winapi/CamelToPascalCaseFunctionMapper.java#L11))

To find and show your window (note, I haven't tested this, the Windows API documentation will help you out if it doesn't work):

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class Program {
    private static final int SW_RESTORE = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User32 user32 = Native.loadLibrary("User32.dll", User32.class);
        int window = user32.FindWindowA(null, "Google Chrome");
        boolean success = user32.ShowWindow(window, SW_RESTORE);
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail: " + Native.getLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the window name must also match exactly, otherwise `window` will be 0 (NULL) and the following call will fail. I am also not sure whether SW_RESTORE works alone or if it needs another flag to go with it.

If you want to enumerate through all of the processes to find the one you're interested in, you can check out some examples from my [`lacuna` project](https://github.com/cxcorp/lacuna/tree/master/lacuna/lacuna-core/src/main/java/cx/corp/lacuna/core), the windows/WindowsPidEnumerator.java and windows/WindowsNativeProcessCollector.java files might be useful. A word of warning though, this was a course project and it has disgustingly many layers of abstraction.

Comment: Not sure if it is correct but here's what I tried: https://pastebin.com/8Gw1qHAp @cubrr

Comment: @EugenValentin The only things needed inside the interface are the winapi methods. Did that work as you expected? If not, what happened instead?

Comment: didn't really worked as expected, got an error:  @cubrr

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class bugged.test, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: @EugenValentin I would suggest searching StackOverflow for that error, as it is very common. Also remember to actually download the JNA library or adding it as a dependency to your project, if you're familiar with what that means.